# Gunas and Gods worshipped by persons of the Guna

Tags: puranas, worship, gunas

Sattviks worship  Devatas and divine forms, people of Rajasik nature worship Yakshas/ Rakhsas and the Thamasik natured worship devilish evil spirits. BG. Chapter 17, Shloka 4

So it would appear that the Gods chosen for worship are also indicators of devotees' own nature. It is commonly believed that worship of a God bestows benefits of peace and prosperity/boons etc. but other than that no narrow scoped worship or transfer of nature/Guna takes place.

In which other Puranas are the nature of humans and their preferred worship tendency mentioned? Are there any Puranas/stories in them that state how the character of worshipped God is acquired or transferred to the worshipper? Can there be more references of this wider topic in view of overlapping Gunas in persons?

Comment: You can take a look at this question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3856/do-we-get-the-nature-of-those-gods-whom-we-worship?rq=1

Comment: Possible Dupe or Related: [How do Hindus decide which gods or goddesses to worship?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23882/12304) somewhat similar ref is there in **Kurma Purana**...